# Install python egg in buildout environment including data files

Tags: python, django, buildout, egg

*This question assumes that the python package I want to install is a django app that includes templates and media files. But the question is valid for any python package that does not only contain `.py` files.*

I'm using buildout to create a re-buildable environment in which I'm developing a django project. My `buildout.cfg` looks like that:

```
[buildout]
parts = python
eggs =
  normal-python-package
  python-package-with-data-files
find-files = 
  http://domain-to-python-package-with-data-files

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
```

(and some django related stuff). The `python-package-with-data-files` is available through a link on the page `http://domain-to-python-package-with-data-files`.

The eggs `normal-python-package` and `python-package-with-data-files` are installed successfully in the `eggs/` directory. Because `python-package-with-data-files` has set `zip_safe` to `False` in its `setup.py` file it is available unzipped in `eggs/`.

Only the non `.py` files of `python-package-with-data-files` are not available in the unzipped egg in `eggs/` (they *are* included in the `.tar.gz` package available at `http://domain-to-python-package-with-data-files`).

How do I get these data files to be included in the egg? Do I need to change the `setup.py` file of the package? Or is it buildout related?

The things I found out are the following:

If I make a `python setup.py sdist` in `python-package-with-data-files` root directory, all data files are included in the created .tar.gz file. But if I make a `python setup.py bdist` it results in a build without including the data files.

This makes me think that the problem is not buildout specific. But maybe there is a way to tell buildout not to make a `bdist` but a `sdist` to create the egg and install the package into the project.

What shall I do? I am the maintainer of `python-package-with-data-files`, so I can change `setup.py` if necessary.

Comment: After some more researching I found my final solution: Use a
[MANIFEST.in](http://docs.python.org/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute)
file and use `include_package_data = True` in my `setup.py`. I tried this out
earlier but thought it doesn't affect the media files. What went wrong is that
the `sdist` and `bdist` commands used a cached version of the filelist from
`package….egg-info/` directory. So its important to delete this directory
before you run `sdist` and `bdist`. Thanks Carl Meyer for motivating me to
continue my journey :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to make use of the [package_data keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data) in your setup.py file, so distutils knows those files should be installed with your package.

Comment: I already tried this out but it was still not adding the data files. After you mentioned it here I tried *again* and now it works. I found out that it's important to use paths that are relative to the package - and not relative to the project root. *Thank you!* It works now.

Comment: Thankyou @GregorMüllegger, had not clocked they were relative to the package and not the project root / setup.py! Took me long enough.